# Is there excel function or simple macro to determine if text is left or right in the cell?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, alignment, formula

I have a one column with many rows. Each row is containing text. Some text is aligned left, some in middle and some on right.

I would like to have a second column, where each row would receive a value: if the text is aligned on left, then "LEFT", if in middle then "MIDDLE" etc.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no formula for determining cell alignment.
You can however create a UDF (User Defined Function) with VBA to achieve this.

For example, if you place the following in a module in VBA...

```
Function CELL_ALIGNMENT(r As Range) As String

    Select Case r.HorizontalAlignment
        Case -4131
            CELL_ALIGNMENT = "LEFT"
        Case -4108
            CELL_ALIGNMENT = "CENTER"
        Case -4152
            CELL_ALIGNMENT = "RIGHT"
        Case Else
            CELL_ALIGNMENT = "OTHER"
    End Select

End Function
```

...and then in cell B1 type the following...

```
=CELL_ALIGNMENT(A1)
```

...this will tell you the alignment of the text in cell A1.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is creating an UDF in VBA:

> **[User Defined Functions](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html)**

You could do 3 functions: 1 for getting horizontal aligment, other for vertical one and last one to convert those numeric values into text:

```
Public Function GET_H_ALIGN(ByVal rng As Range) As String
If rng.Count <> 1 Then
    GET_H_ALIGN = "ERROR"
Else
    GET_H_ALIGN = CONVERT_XL(rng.HorizontalAlignment)
End If
End Function

Public Function GET_V_ALIGN(ByVal rng As Range) As String
If rng.Count <> 1 Then
    GET_V_ALIGN = "ERROR"
Else
    GET_V_ALIGN = CONVERT_XL(rng.VerticalAlignment)
End If
End Function

Private Function CONVERT_XL(ByVal vValue As Long) As String
Select Case vValue
    Case Is = -4160
        CONVERT_XL = "Left"
    Case Is = -4131
        CONVERT_XL = "Left"
    Case Is = -4108
        CONVERT_XL = "Center"
    Case Is = -4152
        CONVERT_XL = "Right"
    Case Is = -4107
        CONVERT_XL = "Right"
    Case Is = 1
        CONVERT_XL = "None"
    Case Else
        CONVERT_XL = "Error"
End Select
End Function
```

[image]

The function CONVERT_XL is needed to convert the numeric constant into a text value. You can see the options here:

> **[Constants Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants?view=excel-pia)**